# iOS Swift: nil IBOutlets with custom ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Evening I have a problem with outlets.

**viewController1** make several instances of **ViewController2**, presenting them into a page container controlled with a pageControl.

The problem is that the view controller outlets in the **ViewController2** are always nil.

Probably because the ViewController2 is instantiate via code.

How can I fix this?

**here I create the different ViewController2**

```
let page = OnboardPageViewController(onboard: onboard)
            pages.append(page)
```

Here is the init code for ViewController2

```
    //--------------------
    //MARK: - Outlets
    //--------------------

    @IBOutlet var backgroundVideoView: BackgroundVideo!
    @IBOutlet var backgroundUIImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

    //--------------------
    //MARK: - Properties
    //--------------------

    let onboard: Onboard

    //--------------------
    //MARK: - View's Methods
    //--------------------

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("loaded: \(onboard.title)")

        //FIXME: - need to find a way to link the outlets even if the controller is called via code
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        print("presenting: \(onboard.title)")
    }

    init(onboard: Onboard) {
        self.onboard = onboard
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

Comment: Please include the controller instantiation code

Comment: @Alladinian check it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate through UIStoryboard object, something like this:

```
if let viewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "YourStoryBoardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") {
   // do something with it
}
```

You can cast it to your custom class in at the same time of the unwrap (with `as? CustomClassViewCotroller`)

Edit: static func to instantiate your view controller like init:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    static func instantiate(withViewModel vm: ViewModel) -> YourViewController? {
        if let viewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "YourStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as? YourViewController {
            viewController.viewModel = vm

            return viewController
        }

        return nil
    }

    var viewModel: ViewModel?

    // ...

}
```

There will be more optional unwrapping in your code when using `viewModel` var but I think this is the correct way to create view controllers programmatically (in segues you have to set variables too, but that is another history).

Good luck mate.

Comment: don't use a custom init.  Add properties to your VC and set them after you instantiate via the storyboard

Comment: As Lou Franco said, you can set your view controller view model after the story board instantation. I usually have an static method in every view controller which do all instantation with 1 call.

Answer (score 1):

Your outlets will be `nil` until the Storyboard file is loaded. So, right after init, they will be nil.  You have to wait until `viewDidLoad` is called before accessing them.

If you need to `init` and set up things in the VC, you have to add other (non outlet) properties to hold that information. You can't just init and then access an outlet.

EDIT: In your code (added later), you aren't using a XIB or Storyboard.  But, since you have outlets, I am assuming that you actually have one.

Don't use a custom init. Instead add properties and set them after you initialize using a Storyboard instantiate.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, can you make an example?

Comment: See Jose's answer for how to instantiate from a storyboard.  Inside the `if let`, set viewController.onboard.